# Arel table query for where -> has_one through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause, arel

I am trying to use an arel table query to perform a 'where' query on a has_one relationship. The has_one relationship is necessary as it's currently set up as a 'has_one_through'.

The reason for using an arel table query is that this query logic will be dynamic. There are several has_one relationships that need to be queried separately so I want to be as dry and scalable as possible.

The query I am trying to replicate looks a little like this.

Query I want to replicate ('style/s' keyword would be dynamic)

```rb
Book.includes(:style).where(styles: {id: 8})
```

What I've tried so far

```rb
object = Style.find(8)
object_key = object.model_name.i18n_key
object_table = Arel::Table.new(object_key)
has_one = object_table[:id].eq(object.id)

Book.includes(object_key).where(has_one)
```

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what the goal is here. Can you please explain a bit more? What do you mean "'style/s' keyword would be dynamic"? Why do you believe `Arel` is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this without using `Arel` by using `pluralize` on the `object_key`

```rb
object = Style.find(8)
object_key = object.model_name.i18n_key

Book.includes(object_key).where(object_key.to_s.pluralize => { id: object.id })
```

If you want to use `Arel` anyway you can do next:

```rb
object = Style.find(8)
object_key = object.model_name.i18n_key
object_table = Arel::Table.new(object_key.to_s.pluralize)
Book.joins(object_key).where(object_table[:id].eq(object.id))
```

Comment: I had thought about doing this but as I was using Arel already for another part of the query, I had kind of dismissed it. It's quite an elegant solution though. Thank you for putting that together. I think I will use this for the time being

Comment: You're welcome, and check my update;)